# Vim --remote-expr example

Tags: vim

Since my google-fu is failing me, can anyone give me a simple example on how to use `--remote-expr` or any other command line trick to insert text to current buffer, or to set a cfile. (Any : -command would be good.)

All I manage to get with `--remote-expr` is `E449: Invalid expression received` for anything.

Comment: Please stop voting vim questions as offtopic.  They belong on SO, not SU.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:help E449` leads you to a basic example. Unfortunately it is a bit too basic:

> ```
> remote_expr({server}, {string} [, {idvar}])
> ```
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> :echo remote_expr("gvim", "2+2")
> :echo remote_expr("gvim1", "b:current_syntax")
> ```

In command line, that turns into

```
 $ vim --servername "gvim" --remote-expr "2+2"
 4
```

To get an idea what you can do with expressions, see `:help expr`.

### Ordering Vim to insert text from Command line

You are better off with `--remote-send` that sends key sequences in similar manner as you'd do with `map`s or `abbr`s:

```
$ vim --servername Foo --remote-send "GoHello world! <ESC>"
```

will append a new line at the end of the active window's buffer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute a command, let's say `:ls`, to get a list of buffers, you can do

```
vim --servername GVIM --remote-expr "execute(\"ls\")"
```

This will print the list of all buffers in GVIM server. Note the escaped quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for exactly this. For quoting, you can also use this fractionally easier syntax `vim --servername VIM1 --remote-expr "execute('ls')"`.